# Codeigniter File Upload error: 'You did not select a file to upload'

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter 3, getting error like `You did not select a file to upload.` in `do_upload()` function, but normal php function `move_uploaded_file()` works fine. i referred most of the answers from stackoverflow but i did not get solution.

I think it may be in `wamp` issue, but i did not get clearly where it is.
if this code works in your machine then it will be issue in my wamp php or Apache settings.

**View: (upload.php)**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php echo form_open_multipart('welcome/do_upload'); ?>
    <input id="sfile" type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**Controller: (welcome.php)**

```
function do_upload()
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '100';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload()) //not working
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            var_dump($error);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        }
        echo $basename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$config['upload_path'].$basename);
        // move_uploaded_file() works fine
    }
```

Comment: Try to pass field name in `$this->upload->do_upload('file')` and check

Comment: @Saty yes i tried same issue

Comment: Check size of file you have uploaded because you set `$config['max_size'] = '100';`. It means you will not able yo upload file size for more then 100 kb

Comment: also please check permission of your uploads directory.

Comment: @Saty your first solution is right. before i tried like that but i did not get now it is working. i am testing now

Comment: @SashantPardeshi i think permission is okk because OP will able to upload image using `move_uploaded_file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AS per CI 3 you need to pass name attribute in your `$this->upload->do_upload('')`.

So you need to pass name attribute in it

```
$this->upload->do_upload('file');
```

Check size of file you have uploaded because you set $`config['max_size'] = '100';`. It means you will not able to upload file size for more then 100 kb

Read [File Uploading Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html)

Answer (score 1):

It could be related to a post loss due to 301-error.

Try replacing

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('welcome/do_upload'); ?>
```

with (work around)

```
<form action="do_upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

If it works, there's some error in routing configs

Answer (score 0):

First load upload library and then after initialize config data.

And pass attribute name of your input file type in $this->upload->do_upload('file').

```
function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);  # Load upload library
    $this->upload->initialize($config);   # Initialize 
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file')) 
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        var_dump($error);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    }

}
```